# What are the differences between running a nodelet standalone and running the same nodelet alone in a manager?

Tags: ros, rosconsole, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm starting to write a new node(let) and initially wrote my launch file to start that nodelet 'standalone'. However I noticed that messages from the rosconsole macros (`ROS_INFO()`, `ROS_ERROR` and the like -- and there is no difference if I use the nodelet wrapper versions, i.e. `NODELET_INFO()` etc.) were not showing up. I tried initially mucking around with logger levels but that didn't seem to have an effect. Then I tried starting a nodelet manager and loading my nodelet into the manager. Then the messages appeared.

I'd been (mistakenly I suppose) assuming that for all intents and purposes running a nodelet 'standalone' and running a single nodelet within a nodelet manager were equivalent but it seems that this isn't the case, at least for the output of the rosconsole logging macros.

So my question is, is what I've observed expected behaviour and are there any other differences to be aware of when running a nodelet 'standalone'? Aside from requiring one less `<node>` tag in a launch file is there any advantage of using the standalone method as opposed to loading a single node into a nodelet manager?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10799/what-are-the-differences-between-running-a-nodelet-standalone-and-running-the-same-nodelet-alone-in-a-manager?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There should be no difference.  The "standalone" mode simple creates a manager in the local process and loads the Nodelet into that manager, instead of making the request remotely.  If you can create simple test case for the logger appearing vs not between the two modes file a ticket and I'll look at it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-03**:
Ticket #5112 (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5112).